# Storing Data of custom class in HashSet in sorted order

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I have below bean class

```
public class ElectricityReading {

    private Instant time;
    private BigDecimal reading; // kW

    public ElectricityReading() { }

    public ElectricityReading(Instant time, BigDecimal reading) {
        this.time = time;
        this.reading = reading;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ElectricityReading that = (ElectricityReading) o;
        return Objects.equals(time, that.time);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(time);
    }

    public BigDecimal getReading() {
        return reading;
    }

    public Instant getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setReading(BigDecimal reading){
        this.reading=reading;
    }
}
```

I need to store these result in `HashSet`.Actually i dont want to store `time` twice. if it repeats I need to either ignore or overwrite(Both will work ,its POC). Thats why I took time in `equals` and `hashCode` method.
I am writing `HashSet` code like below.

```
public List<ElectricityReading> generate(int number) {
        Set<ElectricityReading>reading= new HashSet<>();

        Instant now = Instant.now();

        Random readingRandomiser = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            double positiveRandomValue = Math.abs(readingRandomiser.nextGaussian());
            BigDecimal randomReading = BigDecimal.valueOf(positiveRandomValue).setScale(4, RoundingMode.CEILING);
            ElectricityReading electricityReading = new ElectricityReading(now.minusSeconds(i * 10), randomReading);
            if(!reading.contains(electricityReading.getTime())){
                reading.add(electricityReading);
            }else {
                electricityReading.setReading(electricityReading.getReading());
            }
        }
        List<ElectricityReading> readings = new ArrayList<>(reading);
        readings.sort(Comparator.comparing(ElectricityReading::getTime));
        return readings;
    }
```

I am storing element in `List` because I need data in sorted order. is there anyway to improve this.
in below output last 2 values are getting repeated.

```
[
    {
        "time": "2021-09-15T20:13:51.268560800Z",
        "reading": 2.5574
    },

    {
        "time": "2020-11-29T08:00:00Z",
        "reading": 1.7
    },
    {
        "time": "2020-11-29T08:00:00Z",
        "reading": 1.7
    }
]
```

Comment: You have duplicates because your set `Set<ElectricityReading>reading` is storing ElectricityReading objects and you are checking if it doesn't contain any Instant objects, which is always true. Besides the else part makes no sense : get value -> set value

Comment: Could you please suggest, how can I get correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

You are working too hard.

- No need to override any methods such as `equals` & `hashCode`.
- No need to make a `List` later. We can keep the elements ordered in certain kinds of sets.
- The use of an ordered set automatically eliminates duplicates, if we specify a comparator.

Key code:

```
NavigableSet < ElectricityReading > readings = 
    new TreeSet <>( 
        Comparator.comparing( ElectricityReading :: time ) 
    )
;
```

## Details

For brevity, I will use the [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature in Java 16+ to briefly write the class. You could just as well use a conventional class.

```
record ElectricityReading( Instant time , BigDecimal readingKwh ) { }
```

### `NavigableSet`

If you want a set to keep its values in a certain order, use a [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) (or `SortedSet`). Java comes with a few implementations of `NavigableSet`, one of which is [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html).

When constructing the `TreeSet`, pass [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) so the navigable set knows how you want the sorting performed. Fortunately, modern Java makes creating a comparator quite easy with the [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)) method that takes a method reference. We use our getter method for accessing our `Instant` field, `ElectricityReading#time` (implicitly created by the compiler in a record), as our method reference for comparisons.

```
NavigableSet < ElectricityReading > readings = new TreeSet <>( Comparator.comparing( ElectricityReading :: time ) );
```

Let's try that out with some sample data. We set up the data intentionally to be out-of-order to verify our set is sorting properly. Notice both the `Instant` values and the `readingKwh` values are increasing in parallel.

I modified your input data, for easier reading.

```java
readings.add( new ElectricityReading( Instant.parse( "2021-09-05T08:00:00Z" ) , new BigDecimal( "1.7" ) ) );
readings.add( new ElectricityReading( Instant.parse( "2021-09-05T08:00:00Z" ) , new BigDecimal( "-666" ) ) );    // Repeated `Instant` value.
readings.add( new ElectricityReading( Instant.parse( "2021-11-05T09:00:00Z" ) , new BigDecimal( "3.1" ) ) );     // Out-of-order.
readings.add( new ElectricityReading( Instant.parse( "2021-10-05T09:00:00Z" ) , new BigDecimal( "2.5574" ) ) );
```

You also asked to prevent elements in the set that have same [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) value, without regard to the [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) value. So let's repeat that first data element. We use a special value for `readingKwh`, `-666`, so we can observe the behavior of [`TreeSet#add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html#add(E)).

Verify by dumping to console.

```
System.out.println( "readings = " + readings );
```

When run.

> readings = [ElectricityReading[time=2021-09-05T08:00:00Z, readingKwh=1.7], ElectricityReading[time=2021-10-05T09:00:00Z, readingKwh=2.5574], ElectricityReading[time=2021-11-05T09:00:00Z, readingKwh=3.1]]

We see two effects, both desired:

- The elements in the set iterate in chronological order by their `Instant` field.
- The repeated object was ignored, as we see the set kept the `1.7` reading. Our `TreeSet` collection rejected our attempt to add the object with `-666`, as its `Instant` value was already found in an existing element of the `NavigableSet`.

Pulling all that code together for your copy-paste convenience.

```java
record ElectricityReading( Instant time , BigDecimal readingKwh ) { }
NavigableSet < ElectricityReading > readings = new TreeSet <>( Comparator.comparing( ElectricityReading :: time ) );

readings.add( new ElectricityReading( Instant.parse( "2021-09-05T08:00:00Z" ) , new BigDecimal( "1.7" ) ) );
readings.add( new ElectricityReading( Instant.parse( "2021-09-05T08:00:00Z" ) , new BigDecimal( "-666" ) ) );    // Repeated `Instant` value.
readings.add( new ElectricityReading( Instant.parse( "2021-11-05T09:00:00Z" ) , new BigDecimal( "3.1" ) ) );     // Out-of-order.
readings.add( new ElectricityReading( Instant.parse( "2021-10-05T09:00:00Z" ) , new BigDecimal( "2.5574" ) ) );

System.out.println( "readings = " + readings );
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Java class called `LinkedHashSet` that lets you iterate items in the order in which they were inserted. If you want them to be inserted in random order, and then iterated in sorted order, the sort is going to have to happen *somewhere*. It's possible that an ordered collection like `TreeSet` might be a better choice in that case?

Comment: Thank you. Could you please help me with code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a set since you have a local variable `now` and you are substracting `i * 10` seconds from it you will not have duplicate time entries. Without changing a lot in your actual implimentation, just do something like:

```
public List<ElectricityReading> generate(int number) {
    List<ElectricityReading> readings = new ArrayList<>();
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    Random readingRandomiser = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        double positiveRandomValue = Math.abs(readingRandomiser.nextGaussian());
        BigDecimal randomReading = BigDecimal.valueOf(positiveRandomValue).setScale(4, RoundingMode.CEILING);
        ElectricityReading electricityReading = new ElectricityReading(now.minusSeconds(i * 10), randomReading);
        readings.add(electricityReading);
    }
    readings.sort(Comparator.comparing(ElectricityReading::getTime));
    return readings;
}
```